# Metcalfe's Law, regression / correlation across non-stationary time series vs. stationary data

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I did my undergrad in computer science and have minimal background in statistics (i.e., several courses during my undergrad). I've been working on a side project attempting to validate Metcalfe's Law in the context of the network value of cryptocurrencies (i.e., their price X number of coins in circulation).

Metcalfe's Law states that the value of a network is proportional to the squared number of users on the network (Y = A * X^2), where 
V = value of network
A = a constant
N = # of users on network

I am currently using Bitcoin's daily pricing data across the past ~8 years as a proxy to the value of the network, and daily transaction volume / # unique addresses as a proxy to the number of users on the network (from blockchain.info).

The question I have regarding the project is whether I have to convert the raw non-stationary time-series data into a stationary one before I conduct statistical analysis (e.g., correlation, regression). There's a huge difference in the results:

**Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test on Raw Data**
[image]

**Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test on Differenced Data (First Order Differencing)**
[image]

**Correlation Heatmap on Raw Data**
[image]

**Correlation Heatmap on Differenced Data**
[image]

The main reason I ask is because the two studies I know of that attempt to validate Metcalfe's Law with respect to Facebook and Tencent do not convert non-stationary time series data (e.g., Facebook revenue) into a stationary one before doing a least squares fit.

This has me a bit confused on whether there are instances where it's okay to conduct statistical analysis on non-stationary time series data, and any help would be appreciated.

Just in case it helps, the two studies mentioned are:
(1) From Metcalfe himself: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6636305/
(2) A similar approach, but for both Facebook and Tencent: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11390-015-1518-1

Comment: Welcome to CV Junsu. Your post does not seem to have a ***question*** in it! Stackexchange sites exist to [ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) questions. If you simply want to discuss a topic, another kind of internet resource, such as reddit, or Andrew Gelman's blog might be a better place. Alternately, if you did mean to ask a question, you can click the "edit" link at the lower left to incorporate a question into your post.

Comment: @Alexis I did intend to ask a question, but maybe I got too caught up in explaining the context of the question. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit the text to make the question clearer.

Comment: +1 Thank you. You might be interested in [a question I asked recently about (unit root) non-stationary processes and correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313119/how-to-prove-that-the-probability-of-spurious-correlation-increases-with-random).